# Limiting object instantiations on heap

Tags: c++

Item 26 of "More Effective C++", explains ways to limit the number of objects instantiated for a class with example of

```
class Printer {
public:
 class TooManyObjects{};
 static Printer* makePrinter();
~Printer();
 void submitJob(const PrintJob& job);
 void reset();
 void performSelfTest();
 ...
private:
 static size_t numObjects;
 Printer();
 Printer(const Printer& rhs);
};

size_t Printer::numObjects = 0;

Printer::Printer()
{
 if (numObjects >= 1) {
 throw TooManyObjects();
 }
 //proceed with normal object construction here;
 ++numObjects;
}

Printer* Printer::makePrinter()
{ 
    return new Printer;
}
```

Isn't it checking the number of objects already created

```
 if (numObjects >= 1) {
     throw TooManyObjects();
 }
```

better be placed in member function Printer::makePrinter() instead of being in class constructor, so that we don't allocated memory itself if no more objects are allowed to be created? Or is there something which we gain by putting this check in class constructor which I am missing?

Comment: In the text, it looks like he says you can have the factory function do the check and return null, or you can have the constructor throw.  So clearly he's happy with either way.  It's normal for constructors to throw because that triggers safe cleanup and because they don't have a return type.

Answer (score -1):

You are right in the sense that not allocating memory for an object which can't be constructed is more efficient.

However, in Item 26, More Effective C++, Scott Meyers first suggests having a public default constructor:

```
class Printer {
public:
 class TooManyObjects{}; // exception class for use
 // when too many objects
 // are requested
 Printer();
 ~Printer();
 ...
private:
 static size_t numObjects;
 Printer(const Printer& rhs); // there is a limit of 1
 // printer, so never allow
}; 

Printer::Printer()
{
 if (numObjects >= 1) {
 throw TooManyObjects();
 }
 proceed with normal construction here;
 ++numObjects;
}
```

In this case, checking for the number of instances in the constructor makes more sense since the constructor is public and anyone may call it.

The next suggestion is the one you've asked, and he moves the constructor to the private part of the class. Since the efficiency of the memory allocation is not in the scope of that item, he may not have considered moving the instance count check to the factory method.